# How to make Smooth Accordion jQuery plugin work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this bit of code I need to add to my AngularJS app. How should I do this? I know there are Angular accordion implementations but this is easy and works really well.

```js
$(function() {
 var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
  this.el = el || {};
  this.multiple = multiple || false;

  // Variables privadas
  var links = this.el.find('.link');
  // Evento
  links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
 }

 Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
  var $el = e.data.el;
   $this = $(this),
   $next = $this.next();

  $next.slideToggle();
  $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

  if (!e.data.multiple) {
   $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
  };
 } 

 var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

Comment: Please give a JSFiddle.

Comment: What should I put there?

Comment: Put your jQuery accordion that is working properly..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h5wj5717/1/

Answer (score 0):

After many mistakes I came up with a solution on my own.
If someone will have similar problem here is my code:

```js
angular.module('frontendApp')
  .directive('accordion', function () {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var links = element.find('.link');
        links.on('click', function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          var $next = $this.next();
          $next.slideToggle();
          $this.parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

This does the job.